# Needing help on how to connect my random number array into bubble sort

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the code for my Random number Array and that works. I need to somehow get my random number array into the bubble sort. I know I need std:copy but not sure how to put it all together, and have it show both cout. Any guidance would be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

// This is the Random number Array
    srand (time (NULL));

    const unsigned int sizeOfArray = 10;
    int numberArray [sizeOfArray];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        numberArray [i] = rand() % 100;
        cout << numberArray [i] << endl;
    }


// This is the code for bubble sort

    int myArray [] ;
    int swapHolder = -1;

    for (int index = 0; index <10; index++)
    {
        if (myArray [index] > myArray [index + 1])
        {
            swapHolder = myArray [index + 1];
            myArray [index + 1] = myArray [index];
            myArray [index] = swapHolder;
        }
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
    {
        cout << myArray [index] << ", ";
    }

    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Please *don't* use `srand`/`rand` in new programs. Use the [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header and what it provides. See also; [rand considered harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful). Also, don't use `NULL`, use `nullptr`. And use `std::array` or `std::vector` over C-style arrays any day.

Comment: Don't use raw arrays, use `std::vector`. Don't keep your code in `main`. Create `std::vector generateRandomArray(int numElems);` and `std::vector bubbleSort(const std::vector& input);`

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like C code than C++ code.  C++ vectors are much easier to handle than arrays.  For example to copy numberArray to myArray you'd do

```
int myArray[sizeOfArray];
std::copy(numberArray, numberArray + sizeOfArray, myArray);
```

If you're using vectors

```
auto myVector = numberVector;
```

I question the need to copy the array.  If all you need is to show the results of the random numbers, just print it out before sorting as well as after.  You can then sort the existing array.

In the utility header you'll find std::swap which will efficiently take care of the swapping in one line.

Your bubble sort will not work as is for two reasons.

Your loop goes from 0 to 9 which is the size of the array. In the last iteration you check if myArray [9] > myArray [10]. Since myArray [10] does not exist, you'll get an access violation.

The second problem is that one loop through the array will not sort it.  The largest value will be at the end of the array, but the smallest value has only moved one spot down and is not necessarily at the begining.  The traditional thing to do is to repeat the loop until no more swaps are made.

If this was not homework, then separating out the sort into another function or using the built in sort would make sense as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can make your code for the Bubble sort into a function which takes in an array as a parameter and outputs a new array (this isn't the most efficient way of doing it but since you want both the original and the sorted this is the best method)

so you can do this

```
int bubbleSort(int arr[], int cap){
    // Your code here
}
```

then you can call your function like
`sortedRandomArray = bubbleSort(numberArray, sizeOfArray);`

my syntax might be a tad off but this is the general way of doing things. Its good practice to separate it and make it a function.

Comment: The capacity of the array needs to be passed.  Arrays loose their capacity information when passed to a function.

Comment: Why is your function returning a single integer?  I recommend `bool` instead.  Usually, if you return an array, you return a pointer to a dynamically allocated copy, or a static array or a pointer to the array parameter.  Try returning `int *` with emphasis on the `*`.

Comment: I made some edits to the code to take in the size of your array as well. The leading int should return anything with type int (even an array)

Comment: Sorry, an `int` is not an array.  Returning an array is different syntax.

Comment: bool will just tell you if the array is sorted or not, this code should return a sorted array from a non sorted array - this way you can output both the sorted array and the non-sorted original array (as proof).

Comment: I thought you were using `int` to indicate success or failure.  A function that returns an array would be declared as `int *`.

Comment: That is only true if you are not making a copy - you said in your original question that you want to make a copy. This is the method for making a copy of the array. you would say `Arr2 = BubbleSort(Arr1)`. In this dummy example you will be able to view `Arr1` and `Arr2`